# Event is not firing while redirect from one page to another

Tags: jquery

In my home page i have a search button and its working perfectly but when i redirect to any page of my websites and come back to home page the search button is not working...
this the event binding code for search button

```
$("#search_top_form").delegate("#search_button", "click", function(e) {       
    e.stopPropagation();    
    wrapperConsole('click search');    
    alert("event trigger");                                        
    submitSearchForm();    
    $("#search_top_form").undelegate();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't `undelegate` the event if you want it to continue working. Just remove that undelegate line:

```
$("#search_top_form").delegate("#search_button", "click", function(e) {   
    e.stopPropagation();
    wrapperConsole('click search');
    alert("event trigger");                                    
    submitSearchForm();
});
```

Comment: but if i remove undelegate then for one click event fire multiple time

Comment: I don't know what you mean. Maybe you need to add `e.preventDefault();` to the method?